# Configurações de usuário

Tags: c#, webforms

Sou meio *noob* em `c#` e gostaria de ajuda em uma aplicação que estou rodando.

Nessa aplicação preciso que as configurações do usuário fiquem *Default*, mas não sei um meio para fazer isso.

estou desenvolvendo em WebForms.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Um trecho do que eu tentei fazer:

```
  private void PostTask(HttpClient client)
  {


        client.PostAsync("http://kronos/dotproject/index.php?m=tasks&a=view&task_id=1393",
            new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dosql", "do_updatetask"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task_log_task", (cmbTasks.SelectedItem as Task).IdTask.Substring(43)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task_log_creator", lblNome.Text),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task_log_name", cmbTasks.Text),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task_log_date", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task_log_hours", cmbHoras.Text),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task_log_description", Descricao.Text),       
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email_assignees", "on"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email_task_contacts", "on"),   
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email_project_contacts", "on")    

            })).Wait();

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();     
        /*var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
        settings.SettingsKey = "value";
        settings.Save(); */
    }
```

Comment: Então Vanessa, acho que sua pergunta tá um tanto vaga... O que seu sistema faz ? Que configurações são essas ? Dê um pouco mais de detalhes, se for possível, trechos de códigos que achar pertinentes pra ficar mais fácil.

Comment: Então... ele envia um post de um formulário contendo informações que estão disponíveis para o usuário, só que preciso fazer uma exceção por que certos usuários fazem sempre a mesma coisa nesse formulário... aí para facilitar gostaria de deixar essas informações padronizadas mas não sei como fazer. Um trecho do que eu tentei fazer :

Comment: opa ! não deu para enviar ^^'

Comment: Além de ser c#, que tecnologia a mais você usa ? MVC, Windows Forms, Web Forms, WebAPI... ? Tente detalhar ao máximo as informações. O que não deu pra enviar ?

Comment: Meu código... mas editei minha pergunta com o trecho que queria enviar

Comment: Isso é bom, mas você ta fazendo o sistema em WebForms ?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo !

Comment: conseguiu arrumar? Acredito que você pode fazer uma tela de login antes de fazer as requisições e depois guardar esses dados para os outros dias